# How do I load jquery.inputmask plugin when loading jQuery dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I'm writing a javascript web widget. I load jQuery library as described in [Alex Marandon article](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/). Then I try to load [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) plugin, like this:

```javascript
var input_mask = $("<script>", {src: "http://" + Host +   "/static/inputmask.js"});
input_mask.appendTo('head');
```

Bit got an error, while loading inputmask.js script:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined
```

This is a line in which error is occured:

```javascript
oncomplete: $.noop, //executes when the mask is complete
```

So, I think that plugin does could not find jQuery library. But, $ variable is work in other parts of my script. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using your link to load jQuery, `jQuery` is local to IIFE. Why are you using it?

Comment: Oh, now i'm understood why it does not work. Now, how to make it work?..

Comment: You should provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (jsFiddle?) otherwise it is too broad, not sure what you are doing

Comment: I put a stripped version of my script on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6885ym55/

Comment: I'm sorry but except making jQuery global, i don't see any other solution as jQuery inputmask plugin is looking for global jQuery variable

Comment: Maybe, I can use another script for masking, such as https://bankfacil.github.io/vanilla-masker? I've tried to load it, but got and error: "VMasker is not defined". How I can make it visilble inside IIFE after vanilla-masker script loading?..

Comment: Using `$.getScript()` e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/6885ym55/2/

Comment: Thak you very much. Finally, it works. But, as it revealed, vanila-mask, unfortunataly, is unsuitable for me, because It cannot hanlde hardcoded numbers(+7 in first position, for example) and do not show mask. Please, tell me how can I set jQuery as global variable in my script so than I can use jquery.inputmask plugin. Thank you!

Comment: I'd not use `Alex Marandon article` snippet logic to start with. I'm not sure why would you need it btw.